# Can not delete a local printer port

Tags: printer, network-printer, windows-server

I have added a local printer port with address to a network address. The port started giving problems. So, I tried to delete it by going in printer management but it says the required resource is in use. Turning off printer spooler service did not work. There is no trace of printer port in registry. What should I do?

Comment: *I tried to delete it by going in printer management but it says the required resource is in use.* This means that some printer is attached via this port. Attach that printer to another port (or remove printer at all), then delete port.

Comment: Did you delete the printer in "Printers and Faxes"? This should be done before deleting the port.

Comment: Further to @Akina 's comment, that can be ANY port, even ports that have no printer attached. Try LPT1, FILE, or use the port for some other printer on the network. If you use the last option, just don't print to it as that may cause problems ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer to the problem. I quickly restarted the printer spooler service and deleted the port. If any more time was taken, the port would again give error on deleting.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I had this problem and the solution was pretty simple - in hindsight:

1. select the correct port / port name (even if it is identical to an already listed port, e.g. when using IP printer);
2. hit the apply button, now the port you want to delete is not in use anymore;
3. select the port you want to delete, ignore the V mark that is moving;
4. delete the port;
5. go to 3 if you want to delete more ports;
6. make sure you've got the right port selected again;
7. hit apply or OK button.

This is not as error prone as restarting the services, and giving you only a minimal time frame.

Comment: Of course the printer interface is very, well, 90's. We'll have to wait for Microsoft to screw it up further in the next Windows 10 update by removing all configuration options, and *then* having to revert to the 90's interface.